# In which layer do you place your SignalR logic?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, .net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-webapi

I've been building a simple web application, using asp.net core 3.1 web api with EF core and React for front-end. I decided to implement a chat functionality(1 on 1) and I wanted to use SignalR, so the user gets instant updates, once a new message has been received. I am trying to stick to the SOLID principles as much as possible.

I have several projects.

**Data project** - holding my DbContext, Models, Repositories.

**Services project** - holding my services which communicate with the repositories and perform db queries.

**Web Project** - holding my controllers and my ClientApp(React).

My problem is, I don't know where should my SignalR code be?

Right now it's pretty straightforward - *Client -> Controller -> Service -> Repository -> Db* and reverse.

Answer (score 1):

As you know SignalR provides server-to-client remote procedure calls (RPC). So it is in the same level as a controller. Because it is the first entrance to your API and logic to your server from the client like a controller.

So definitely you SignalR hub should be in the **Web Project** and it will contain all communication logic. Now if you for example need to store the chat in your DB or do other logic you should just inject the manager in your hub using for example DI.